# Issues adding external JDBC jar to applet

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

I am trying to make an applet that accesses a database and reads the table information. I don't care about any security risks whatsoever, just want this to work.

Whenever I run the applet in the appletviewer, it accesses the database just fine and does what I want it to do. However, when I try to add the .class to an HTML website, I get a class not found exception. I've looked around and nothing seems to be working. I have my .class, my JDBC .jar, and my .html all in a folder on a my desktop. Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>applet</title>
</head>

<body>
<applet code="testing.class" width="350" height="200" archive="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar"></applet>
</body>

</html>
```

My applet code (even though I'm sure it's correct):

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class testing extends Applet{
    public void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String URL = "https://ca.news.yahoo.com/-a-kick-in-the-teeth---pc-supporters-respond-to-hudak-s-resignation-195516571.html";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://BLOCKED/BLOCKED", "BLOCKED", "BLOCKED");
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO voting (URL, Votes) VALUES ('" + URL + "', 2) ");
            statement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

New error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at testing.init(testing.java:11)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.encoding" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:69)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Which class is not found: yours of the JDBC driver?

Comment: @AlexR the JDBC driver is not found, my applet's .class is loading just fine.

Comment: Check that your jar is indeed accessible. do the following. Construct URL that where the name of your HTML page is replaced by jar. For example if you access your page as `http://myhost/myapp/mypage.html` try to surf to `http://myhost/myapp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar`. You should be able to download the file.

Comment: @AlexR Yep, I went to the page and the jar was downloaded. I definitely have access to the jar.

Comment: Are you sure you get `ClassNotFoundException`? Could you post full stack trace?

Comment: @AlexR I'm not sure if it's because I cleared my applet console or what, but it is not displaying the stack trace at all now. However, my applet still is getting an error when loading. Not sure how to get the console to print the stack trace again, or even what is happening.

Comment: @AlexR after restarting Chrome the issue still persisted, so I ran my applet on Internet Explorer and the console showed a completely different error. It has been posted to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this exception is reasonable.

Your problem is in the beginning. You try to run applet that connects directly to JDBC. You noted that security issues are out of scope. Probably it is correct from your point of view but not from the point of view of your browser.

Applets are very limited in security perspective. They cannot use client's disk, cannot call JNI, cannot establish connection to server other than one that they started from.

In your case you run your page from file system, i.e. use URL like `c:/myproject/mypage.html`. This means that your "host" is something like "myproject". Then you try to perform JDBC connection to `BLOCKED` (i guess it is `localhost`. But `localhost` is not `myproject`. To solve this security problem try to deploy your applet under HTTP server (even if it is on your computer). Then try to access the page over HTTP.

As far as I remember you should also sign your applet. Probably you can configure your browser to run untrusted applets. In this case you can run it without signing.

I still do not know what was the problem in Chrome.

BUT: why are you doing all this? Applets is an obsolete technology. No-one uses it for last 15 years. If you just need some kind of java UI, implement java application. If you need some kind of easy distribution run it using java web start. Or alternatively implement ordinary web application, so client talks to server over HTTP and server performs all connections it needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out and get back to you. The reason I am using an applet is because I needed to create both an application AND and applet for my CS class. I wish my teacher would understand that applets are pretty much obsolete, but I guess he's just living in the past.

Comment: Well, good luck with your teacher... Just avoid applet to access JDBC directly. You can create servlet that exposes simple RESTful API and make applet to talk to this servlet.

Comment: So I've been playing around, and I still have gotten no where. You mentioned that you thought my mySQL database was local, but it is an actual database I have paid for. My goal was to be able to load the applet locally, and still have it be able to access my SQL database. Is this not possible?

Comment: I think my description was not clear. Again, applet can open socket to host from where it was downloaded. The host names are compared as strings. For example even if you surf to `http://localhost/bla` and then open socket to `127.0.0.1` you fail on security restriction. When you start your applet not over HTTP the host name is "fake", so all your attempts to open socket will fail. Try to access over HTTP.